# Django : Creating an on-click trigger

Tags: django

My Django website involves displaying number of times a song on the website has been played, if someone could help me out in adding the right trigger that increments a counter each time a click to that webpage hosting the song is encountered, it would be much appreciated.

Code written :

In models.py

```
class SongPlays(models.Model):
songid = models.ForeignKey(Songs, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
songhits = models.IntegerField( ? )
```

In views.py, for another table 'Songs'

```
def detail(request, songid):
try:
    song = Songs.objects.get(pk=songid)
except Songs.DoesNotExist:
    raise Http404("Song does not exist")
return render(request, 'music/detail.html', {'song': song} )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand the question, but I think that once the view named detail is accessed you wish to increment the song hit count. You could just add a database query after the song is accessed to increase the value by 1.

```
def detail(request, songid):
    try:
        song = Songs.objects.get(pk=songid)
        song_play = SongPlays.objects.filter(songid=song)
        SongPlays.objects.filter(songid=song).update(songhits=F('songhits')+1)
    except Songs.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("Song does not exist")
    return render(request, 'music/detail.html', {'song': song} )
```

Note: I used filter() instead of get() so that you can update all SongPlay entries associated with a Song. If you only have one SongPlay to update, you should use get(), but then update() won't work. You would need to do something like;

```
song_play.songhits = F('songhits') + 1
song_play.save()
```

Be careful with your use of Foreign Key. Do you want this to be a one-to-one relationship, i.e., should there only be one SongPlay entry for each Song. At present you could have many SongPlay entries for one Song.

If the only item you are adding to the Song DB is the number of hits, could this just be added as a field to the Song model?

Comment: Use an [F-expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions) instead to avoid race conditions. `SongPlays.objects.filter(songid=song).update(songhits=F('songhits')+1)`

Comment: Thank you! yes, I shall add Song hits as a field to Songs class itself. And yes, it will be a 1:1 relationship since I'm recording the number of views a song gets, like YouTube, will my code not work for that? And may I ask why so?

Comment: Foreign Key fields build a many-to-one field. You should really specify it as a ono-to-one field if that's what you need to prevent errors. You can read about these at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#module-django.db.models.fields.related.